# Why my form is not sending data with POST in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, request, laravel-form

I'm creating my login page with Laravel

I want send my login form datas with POST method, but is not working

```
// /view/login.blade.php
/*
{{ Form::open([
    "route" => "user/login",
    "autocomplete" => "off",
    'method' => 'POST'
]) }}
    {{ Form::label("username", "Usuário:") }}
    {{ Form::text("username", Input::old("username"), [
        "placeholder" => "john.smith"
    ]) }}
    {{ Form::label("password", "Senha:") }}
    {{ Form::password("password", [
        "placeholder" => "*******"
    ]) }}
    {{ Form::submit("Entrar") }}
{{ Form::close() }}

//---------------------------------------
// routes.php
Route::any( '/', [
"as" => "user/login",
    "uses" => "UserController@loginAction"
] );

//---------------------------------------
// /controllers/UserController.php
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        echo Input::server( "REQUEST_METHOD" );  // This line is ever print "GET"
        return View::make( 'user/login' );
    }
}*/
```

[Code edited]

```
// view/login.blade.php
<form action="{{URL::to('/')}}" method="post">
    <input name="login" type="text"/><br/>
    <input type="password" name="senha" id=""/><br/>
    {{ Form::submit('Enviar') }}
</form>

// routes.php
Route::any('/', function()
{
    echo Request::getMethod();   is returning GET forever
    return View::make( 'login' );
});
```

Apparently, my form will send datas with POST method, but I can never get they in $_POST, why?

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
Input::all()
```

to get all the data

or `Input::get('username')`, `Input::get('password')` and so on to get selected data.

Comment: Yes, I can get data with GET, but why POST method is not working?

Comment: @Lai32290 All the data you get using this method, both GET and POST.

Comment: I have simplify my code, only for test, but my echo Request::getMethod(); is ever return GET, why?